# Comparing a jagged matrix that has duplicates to a LinkedHashSet with all these links returns null

Tags: comparison

Comparing a jagged matrix that has duplicates to a LinkedHashSet with all these links returns null when more apparitions from the matrix occurs. I want to create another matrix with the same size of the first matrix but only with the indexes from the linkedHashSet.

If my initial matrix is like:

```
link1 link2
link3 link2 link2
```

my LinkedHashSet is

```
link1
link2
link3
```

and my last matrix i want to be

```
1 2
3 2 2
```

My code:

arr - my matrix with strings
brr1 - my linked hash set with the links(i didn't  need duplicates)
indexArr - my final matrix

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++){
                for(int k = 0; k < brr1.size(); k ++){      
                    if(arr[i][j]==brr1.get(k)){
                        indexArr[i][j] = k;

                    }
                }
        System.out.println();
            }
        }
```